# Getting error when i load SSH key "Load key "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519": error in libcrypto"

Tags: git, ssh

Long story short I have an SSH key pair that I am copying to a new machine from a shared drive whenever the machine starts but when I load in the keys I keep getting an error

```
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519": error in libcrypto
```

However when I then create a new SSH keypair it works perfectly fine. Is there some restrictions about copying keys or are they bound to the machine it was created on?

A bit more background is that I am using this to read from my private Github repo,

```
cp [filepath to ssh pub key on shared drive] "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
cp [filepath to ssh private key on shared drive] "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519"

ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod go-rwx /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout git@github.com:account/repo.git
```

I have no idea what is going on, and when i print the contents of the two key pairs they are identical, but it seems like the moment a new machine is booted it stops working - any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

Comment: I would like to refer your attention to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and specifically paragraph 1 bullet point 3, that specifically mentions software tools used for programming (github and SSH), I have read the help pages which is why I posted - as such i would appreciate you deleting this off-handed comment. Thank you

Comment: @JohnDoePython, SSH is not a programming-specific tool. It's probably used more often by system administrators than anyone else. It's not enough for something to used by developers; it needs to be used _exclusively_ by developers (the specific wording in our help center is "unique to software development") to be on-topic here.

Comment: (No, there are no restrictions about copying keys; I'd look for things like UNIX newlines being converted to DOS ones or changes of that sort; or, better, use a hardware keystore like your system's TPM unit or a Yubikey or smartcard and stop storing keys _anywhere a general-purpose CPU can read them_ in the first place)

Comment: (the "unique to" wording is in the fourth bullet point; combined with the one you quoted from with an "and" condition, not an "or").

Comment: How exactly is the shared directory shared? What is the filesystem and how is it mounted?

Comment: This question still refers to the usage of ssh, git, and github - I am not sure how those are not tools used by programmers, especially the last 2, and exclusively can't be literally applied because no tool is exclusively used by anyone, which is likely also why there are a lot of these questions here, which I have seen because I searched extensively before I asked.

In terms of the directory, it is a persistent volume mounted to a pod, I am only using these SSH key pairs to give read access to a very specific private repo, so there are no material security issues.